# WinForms Vista style tool strip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-vista, aero

How can I achive a native Windows look and feel using a `toolStrip` control?

**What I want:**
[image]

**What it currently looks like:**
[image]

Note that the background is completely different (ignore the icons).

Comment: Use `System` as Renderer and set `BackColor`. If it was not satisfying create a new `ToolStripRenderer` yourself.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Setting the `BackColor` wouldn't adjust to the theme the user selected, would it? How would I go about creating a custom `ToolStripRenderer` that imitates a system look?

Comment: System renderer uses system visual style colors.